# How to use a templated function in C++ for two types in Cython?

Tags: python, c++, templates, cython

I have a templated C++ function of which I would like to be able to use both types. As Python does not support overloading, I am a little stuck how to solve this. I have a `.pyx` as shown below. How can I use the C++ function in both `float` and `double`?

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# declare the interface to the C code
cdef extern from "diff_cpp.cpp" namespace "diff":
    cdef void diff_cpp[float] (float* at, const float* a, const float visc,
                               const float dxidxi, const float dyidyi, const float dzidzi,
                               const int itot, const int jtot, const int ktot)

cdef extern from "diff_cpp.cpp" namespace "diff":
    cdef void diff_cpp[double] (double* at, const double* a, const double visc,
                                const double dxidxi, const double dyidyi, const double dzidzi,
                                const int itot, const int jtot, const int ktot)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def diff(np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] at not None,
         np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] a not None,
         double visc, double dxidxi, double dyidyi, double dzidzi):
    cdef int ktot, jtot, itot
    ktot, jtot, itot = at.shape[0], at.shape[1], at.shape[2]
    diff_cpp[double](&at[0,0,0], &a[0,0,0], visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi, itot, jtot, ktot)
    return None

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def diff_f(np.ndarray[float, ndim=3, mode="c"] at not None,
           np.ndarray[float, ndim=3, mode="c"] a not None,
           float visc, float dxidxi, float dyidyi, float dzidzi):
    cdef int ktot, jtot, itot
    ktot, jtot, itot = at.shape[0], at.shape[1], at.shape[2]
    diff_cpp[float](&at[0,0,0], &a[0,0,0], visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi, itot, jtot, ktot)
    return None
```

---

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

The answer of @oz1 provided the correct way of doing this. This the code that works, for those who are interested in the solution to this particular problem.

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# declare the interface to the C code
cdef extern from "diff_cpp.cpp" namespace "diff":
    cdef void diff_cpp[T](T* at, const T* a, const T visc,
                          const T dxidxi, const T dyidyi, const T dzidzi,
                          const int itot, const int jtot, const int ktot)

ctypedef fused float_t:
    cython.float
    cython.double

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def diff(np.ndarray[float_t, ndim=3, mode="c"] at not None,
         np.ndarray[float_t, ndim=3, mode="c"] a not None,
         float_t visc, float_t dxidxi, float_t dyidyi, float_t dzidzi):
    cdef int ktot, jtot, itot
    ktot, jtot, itot = at.shape[0], at.shape[1], at.shape[2]
    diff_cpp(&at[0,0,0], &a[0,0,0], visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi, itot, jtot, ktot)
    return None
```

Comment: just spitballing, have you tried making a typedef for the specific template instantiations, and giving that non-template name to python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two notes:

1. Cython supports c++ template(http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html)
2. Cython has fused types(http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html)

An example:

```
// lib.cpp
template<typename T>
T arr_sum(T *arr, size_t size)
{
    T temp=0;
    for (size_t i=0; i != size; ++i){
        temp += arr[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

---

```
# lib_wrapper.pyx
cimport cython

ctypedef fused  float_t:
    cython.float
    cython.double

cdef extern from "lib.cpp" nogil:
    T arr_sum[T](T *arr, size_t size)

def py_arr_sum(float_t[:] arr not None):
    print(sizeof(arr[0]))  # check the element size
    return arr_sum(&arr[0], arr.shape[0])
```

---

```
# use.py
import numpy as np
from lib_wrapper import py_arr_sum

print(py_arr_sum(np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float32)))
print(py_arr_sum(np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)))
print(py_arr_sum(np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int32)))  # oops
```

Comment: I did not know about these fused types. That seems pretty awesome.